# matrixEQTL R-too many associations

Tags: r, p-value, bonferroni

I have used `matrixEQT`L R package using `1,002,800` SNPs, `29,000` genes and a Bonferroni correction of p-value `1.4e-12`. I have `400` samples and used the first five `principal components` as covariates. It has given `1148000` cis associations and `73136000` trans associations. I have checked other studies with comparative number of genes and SNPs resulting in around `3000` cis and `95000` trans associations. I have used:

```
me = Matrix_eQTL_main(
snps = snps, 
gene = gene, 
cvrt = cvrt,
output_file_name     = output_file_name_tra,
pvOutputThreshold     = 1.6e-12,
useModel = useModel, 
errorCovariance = numeric(),
verbose = TRUE, 
output_file_name.cis = output_file_name_cis,
pvOutputThreshold.cis = 1.6e-12,
snpspos = snpspos, 
genepos = genepos,
cisDist = cisDist,
pvalue.hist = FALSE,
min.pv.by.genesnp = FALSE,
noFDRsaveMemory = FALSE);
```

Please help me to understand why I am getting too many associations? Thank you!